# Check integrity of UEFI file: How do I know if my UEFI has been compromised by malware or by someone?

Tags: windows-8, security, bios, uefi, malware

If anyone could answer these three questions:

Computer model: Dell Inspiron 3543

1. Is there a way to check the integrity of the UEFI file, as in the file itself and not just its settings?
2. How do I know if malware has secretly infected the UEFI file or someone messed with it without me knowing?
3. Is there a way to restore the UEFI file back to how it was in the start?